# Any value in a formula that calculates (not look up) the 'order' of a 'Independent Edge Set' OR a 'I.E.S.' given an 'order' on complete graphs?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, np-complete, clique, independent-set

Any value or interest in a formula that calculates (not look up) the 'integer order' of a given 'Independent Edge Set' OR given an 'Independent Set' calculates the 'integer order' on Complete Graphs? The Mappings of Perfect Matchings on a Complete Graph. Likewise for Cliques.

Example:
n=8, k=2
vertices: 8
edge count: 28
perfect matchings: 105
vertice set: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

Order: Independent Edge Set (Perfect Matching)
1: {1,2}{3,4}{5,6}{7,8}
2: {1,2}{3,4}{5,7}{6,8}
3: {1,2}{3,4}{5,8}{6,7}
…
105: {1,8}{2,7}{3,6}{4,5}

Comment: Applies to any integer 'k' as well. ie: n=9,k=3. ({1,2,3}{4,5,6}{7,8,9}...

Comment: I ask because I can do this and have a proof that it is always accurate. And, I am not aware of the existence of anything similar.